# For a non homogeneous system of linear equation $Ax=b$, can we conclude any relation between rank of $A$ and dimension of the solution space?

Tags: linear-algebra

For homogenous system of linear equation $Ax=0$ we can say that the nulity of the matrix A and the dimension of the solution space is same.But I cannot find any relation for non homogeneous system of linear equation.So please help me.Thank you in advance

Comment: When $b \neq 0$, the solution space to $Ax = b$ will not be a linear subspace.  It will, however, be an affine subspace.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If $x_0$ is any solution of $Ax_0 = b$, then $Ax = b$ if and only if $A(x - x_0) = 0$.